# Jsoup Java get a specific td

Tags: java, html, web-scraping, jsoup, html-table

I have the following code

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.*;

import org.jsoup.*;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;
import java.io.*;
public class da {

/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {


            Document doc=Jsoup.connect("http://www.vremea.net/").get();
            Elements e=doc.select(".homeContent ul li a ");
            PrintStream ps=new PrintStream(new FileOutputStream("io"));
            String rezultat="";
            for(int i=0;i<e.size();i++)
                if(e.get(i).attr("href").contains("Arad"))
                    rezultat=e.get(i).attr("href");

            System.out.println(rezultat);

            Document doc1=Jsoup.connect(rezultat).get();
            Elements row=doc1.select(".tableforecast tr");
            Elements nume=doc1.select("h1");
            ArrayList<String> date=new ArrayList<String>();
            ArrayList<String> numedate=new ArrayList<String>();

            for(int q=1;q<nume.size();q++)
                if(nume.get(q).text().contains("Vremea in"))
                    numedate.add(nume.get(q).text());
            for(int i=0;i<row.size();i++)
                {
                    Elements col=row.get(i).select("td");
                    String sir="";
                    int vr=0;
                    for(int j=0;j<col.size();j++)
                    if(col.get(j).className().equals("cell large")) 
                        {sir=sir+" "+col.get(j).text();
                    vr=1;}
                    if(vr==1)
                    date.add(sir);

                }
        for(int i=0;i<numedate.size();i++){

            for(int j=0;j<date.size();j=j+2)
                ps.println(numedate.get(i)+"\n"+date.get(j)+"\n"+date.get(j+1));
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


}

 }
```

This code gets in a table and for each row it gets  a column that contains some string. I wonder if I can get those column direct without using contains and get all columns and then get from all those columns what I need and I was wondering what will select looks like if this is possible?

numedate- is the name of the day and date is the temperature and the hour.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may try it this way:

go directly to the page where you want to extract data (In your case "Arad")

"http://www.vremea.net/Vremea-in-Arad-judetul-Arad/prognoza-meteo-pe-7-zile" look at the other pages. They seem to have somekind of structur like : 
/some text-in-place name-some text/some text

You can select the td elements in the class cell and in the class large directly as follows

```
public static void main (String [] args) throws IOException{        
    Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.vremea.net/Vremea-in-Arad-judetul-Arad/prognoza-meteo-pe-7-zile").get();
    Elements tds = doc.select("table.tableforecast tbody tr td.cell.large");
    for (Element e : tds){
        System.out.println(e.text());
    }
}
```

Comment: why did you put . between cell and large?

Comment: cause the td belongs to both classes "cell" and "large"

Comment: and here <td class="cell large bb"><b>20</b>°C</td> td belongs to 3 classes? (cell ,large and bb)